# How to use watch flag in TypeScript with multiple projects?

Tags: typescript, npm, tsconfig

I have following `package.json` scripts section:

```
"watch": "?",
"build": "npm run build:compactor && npm run build:generator && npm run build:cleaner",
"build:lambda": "npm run build:compactor:lambda && npm run build:generator:lambda && npm run build:cleaner:lambda",
"build:compactor": "tsc -p src/compactor",
"build:generator": "tsc -p src/generator",
"build:cleaner": "tsc -p src/cleaner",
"build:compactor:lambda": "npm run build:compactor && cp package.json ./dist-compactor/package.json && cd ./dist-compactor && npm install --production && zip -r ../dist-compactor.zip *",
"build:generator:lambda": "npm run build:generator && cp package.json ./dist-generator/package.json && cd ./dist-generator && npm install --production && zip -r ../dist-compactor.zip *",
"build:cleaner:lambda": "npm run build:cleaner && cp package.json ./dist-cleaner/package.json && cd ./dist-cleaner && npm install --production && zip -r ../dist-compactor.zip *",
```

My project consists of 3 subproject. It has main `tsconfig.json` file and then 3 configs which extend first one.

Standard `tsc -w` will ignore existing nested configuration.

One option would be to concurrently run `tsc -p src/<project> -w` 3 times but maybe `tsc` has something built in already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using UNIX-based system, a workaround might be to use

```
tsc -w -p project1 & tsc -w -p project2
```

To run them concurrently. It will work in terms of compiling the typescript code but you might encounter strange artifacts in the console window unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the following command

```
tsc -w -p project1 & tsc -w -p project2
```

Hope it is helpful